# Loop in javascript to append a series of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, append

This is my code, but it does not work.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
$(function(){
    $('.tt'+ [i]).appendTo('.td'+ [i]);
   });

}
```

---

I want the result:

```
$('.tt1').appendTo('.td1')
$('.tt2').appendTo('.td2')
$('.tt3').appendTo('.td3')
$('.tt4').appendTo('.td4')
$('.tt5').appendTo('.td5')
```

Please correct me, thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors, try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('.tt'+ i).appendTo('.td'+ i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned: remove the array initialization.
If you want to iterate from **1** to **5** then do so (**not var = 0, but var i = 1**):

```
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
       $('.tt'+ i).appendTo('.td'+ i);
    }
```

Also I don't see any sense in wrapping it the appendTo call.

Answer (score 0):

**The 1st Thing**

You will never jump into the i=5 iteration

```
$('.tt5').appendTo('.td5')
```

because your for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

ends at i = 5

Change it to

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
```

It starts at i=1 because your example didn't show a ".tt0"

**The 2nd thing**

Remote the brackets!

Change

```
$('.tt'+ [i]).appendTo('.td'+ [i]);
```

to

```
$('.tt'+ i).appendTo('.td'+ i);
```

Otherwise you will create an Array and the JS interpreter performs an unnecessary Array.toString() operation.

**The 3rd thing**

I think you can remove the surrounding function inside the *for loop*

```
$(function(){
 ... 
}
```

Just use:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   $('.tt'+ i).appendTo('.td'+ i);
}
```

**See Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Spaghettirocker/knkpaczg/1/